# refs is depreciated. refs works but is depreciated. How can we make this code work without using refs keyword here

Tags: reactjs

The below code works fine but refs are depreciated so my question is...
How can I change this refs to non-depreciated code?
Just paste this code in Index.js to run it. That is it. Little Piece of cake.
Stackoverflow : It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
Me : I dont have any more details.

```
class RydoEmployee extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state=
    {
      TotalSalary: this.props.BasicSalary+this.props.HRA+this.props.LTE
    }
  }

  LetsUpdateSalary=(changedsalary)=>{
    this.setState({
      TotalSalary:changedsalary
    });
  }

  render()
  {
    return <div>
      <p>
        <label>Id :{this.props.Id}</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Name :{this.props.Name}</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Location :{this.props.Location}</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Salary :{this.state.TotalSalary}</label>
      </p>
      <Department BasicSalary={this.props.BasicSalary} HRA={this.props.HRA} LTE={this.props.LTE} UpdateSalary={this.LetsUpdateSalary} />
    </div>
  }
}

class Department extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      bs:this.props.BasicSalary,
      hr:this.props.HRA,
      lt:this.props.LTE
    }
  }

  UpdateSalary=()=>{ 
    let changedsalary = parseInt(this.refs.BasicSalary.value) + parseInt(this.refs.HRA.value) + parseInt(this.refs.LT.value);
    this.props.UpdateSalary(changedsalary);
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
      <p>
        <label>Basic Salary: <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.bs} ref="BasicSalary"/></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>HRA: <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.hr} ref="HRA"/></label>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label>LT: <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.lt} ref="LT"/></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button onClick={this.UpdateSalary}>Update</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  }
}

const e = <RydoEmployee Id={101} Name="Vaibhav Singh" Location="Faridabad" BasicSalary={5} HRA={10} LTE={5}/>

ReactDOM.render(e,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated way of using refs is described in [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs):

```js
class Department extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // Create all necessary refs
    this.basicSalaryRef = React.createRef();
    this.hraRef = React.createRef();
    this.ltRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      bs:this.props.BasicSalary,
      hr:this.props.HRA,
      lt:this.props.LTE
    }
  }

  UpdateSalary = () => { 
    // Reference ref.current to get the DOM node
    let changedsalary =
      parseInt(this.basicSalaryRef.current.value) + 
      parseInt(this.hraRef.current.value) + 
      parseInt(this.ltRef.current.value);
    this.props.UpdateSalary(changedsalary);
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
      <p>
        <label>Basic Salary: <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.bs} ref={this.basicSalaryRef} /></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        {/* Attach refs to inputs */}
        <label>HRA: <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.hr} ref={this.hraRef} /></label>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label>LT: <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.lt} ref={this.ltRef} /></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button onClick={this.UpdateSalary}>Update</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  }
}
```